# What is the accuracy of Hypnosis in a battle between Diamond and Platinum versions?

Tags: pokemon-fourth-generation, pokemon-diamond-pearl-platinum

In Pokemon Diamond, Hypnosis has 70% accuracy. In Pokemon Platinum, it has 60%. In a battle between these two games, which value is used?

Comment: Now that's an expert question!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It depends on the host game. If Platinum is hosting, it will be 60%; if Diamond is hosting, it will be 70%.

> On a Wi-Fi battle, if a Plat cart hosts the game, then Hypnosis' accuracy will be 60% for both players, EVEN if the other guy is using D/P. If D/P player is hosting, Hypnosis will be 70%, even if the other guy is using Plat. ([source](http://projectpokemon.org/forums/showthread.php?809-The-Accuracy-of-Hypnosis-in-Wifi&s=989c6abd70ce491d27d55e8277188d7b&p=8814&viewfull=1#post8814))

Comment: source? ~~~~~~~

Comment: There's no official confirmation of the information (by Game Freak or Nintendo), however it has been confirmed on various Pokemon forums.

Comment: So post a link to one of those forum posts